# ASP.NET / VB.NET: Iterate through multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, multiline, loops

I'm trying to iterate through each line of a multiline textbox. Something like:

```
For Each line In Me.txtBox1.Lines
    Response.Write line.Text
Next
```

Is there any neat way to do this, or will I need to write a character-by-character parser and look for carriage returns?

Thanks for any help,

Jason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
For Each line As String In Me.txtBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)
    Response.Write(line)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each line In Me.txtBox1.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Response.Write line
Next
```

Comment: I don't think String has a Text property.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, me neither :-) Fixed.

Comment: @Darin, I was so close! Thanks!

Comment: you don't need `.ToString()` if you using `As String` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `txtBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);`

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

In your case:

```
For Each line In Me.txtBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write line.Text
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this char by char, just use split.

```
txtBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Write (line & "<br />")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer